# C++ SetWindowsHookEx with a controller

Tags: c++, controller, setwindowshookex

Trying to make my A and B buttons on my n64 controller use 2 keys, so far my code is:

```
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
if (hHook== NULL) {
    std::cout << "N64 hook failed!" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm aware WH_KEYBOARD_LL isn't right for a controller, I'm having an issue figuring out what I can do to make it work.